# How can I downgrade the Gradle in NativeScript?

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript, downgrade

In my NativeScript project, after the last Gradle update, I can't build a new Bundle file (for Android release). This error is about the compatibility of some plugins with the new Gradle version.

I think if I could downgrade the Gradle version to the previous one, the build will succeed.

Is any way that I could do the Grandle downgrade on a NativeScript project?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a way to specify the version of `gradle` to use in the project itself. But it is not documented anywhere.

I found these references in their code repository on github:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/search?q=runtimeGradleVersion

However, it is easy to set `gradle` version outside the project in `gradle.properties` file.

---

### Linux

On typical Linux(Debian) nodejs|npm installation, the location of this file is:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/vendor/gradle-plugin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

For example, if you wish to specify the version `6.4` of `gradle`, simply change the line from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{{runtimeGradleVersion}}-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4-bin.zip
```

---

### Windows

The location of the file shall be under:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\nativescript\vendor\gradle-plugin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
```